# Does Jmeter saves the randomly generated email id (pre-processor-user parameters) in the database

Tags: jmeter

I have used Jmeter's pre-processor 'user parameters'to generate random email ids to test singup api, able to susscefully generate and signin. However not able to see the randomly generated email id in the database (using mongoDB), it is not stored in the DB.
Does jmeter saves the email id in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default JMeter doesn't store anything into the database. If your API sign-up process assumes storing email of the signing-up person to the database - something is wrong with your test scenario.

JMeter automatically considers [HTTP Status Codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) below 400 as successful, it doesn't do any checks of the response body so my expectation is that you are receiving pseudo-successful responses having errors or exceptions inside. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your Test Plan - it is capable of visualizing request and response details and inspect them carefully. If there are errors - fix them until you will be happy with your script behavior, after that the listener can be disabled.

You can also use [JMeter Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), i.e. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to validate whether response contains message regarding successful sign up.

Don't forget to add HTTP Header Manager to send the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header as some API servers don't process the requests not having expected MIME type.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more information on APIs load testing.

Comment: Thanks for the information. My tests are passing after doing some modifications, i was assuming details would be stored, now understood data would not be stored in DB.

Comment: Would it be good if these users (created by using signup api and users are not stored in DB) are used as real-time users and get data using CSV data config to simulate real users?